# How to remove this head css styling with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

How would you remove 00bf00 part from this:

```
#main { background:#00bf00 00bf00 url('images/low.png') repeat;  }
```

I need to do this with dynamically, so probably javascript ( or something else if you have idea)

I don't want to change code to output properly, just to see if there is a way to remove it by adding code snippet

Comment: I wouldn't want to bet on browser error recovery not having discarded the rule already. I'd really look at fixing it before it gets delivered to the client.

Comment: yeah you are right, I will fix this to show properly

Comment: @ZarkoDjuric What way are you used to load this style? `link` tag or `style` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// for imported stylesheets
var cssRules = [];
for (var i = 0, il = document.styleSheets.length; i < il; i++) {
    if (document.styleSheets[0].cssRules)
        cssRules = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;
    else if (document.styleSheets[0].rules)
        cssRules = document.styleSheets[0].rules​;
    for (var j = 0, jl = cssRules.length; j < jl; j++) {
        if (/^#main/.test(cssRules[j].cssText))
            cssRules[j].cssText = cssRules[j].cssText.replace(/[^#]00bf00/, '');
    }
}

// for style tags
​var styleTags = document.getElementsByTagName('style');
for (var i = 0, il = styleTags.length; i < il; i++) {
    styleTags[i].innerHTML = styleTags[i].innerHTML
                                         .replace(/(#main.*)[^#]00bf00/, '$1');
}​​
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uP36d/) (for style tags)

Answer (score 0):

you cannot modify css properties directly within the `head` tag, try this:

```
$('#main').css('background-color', "transparent");
```

or:

```
document.getElementById('main').style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
```

Comment: won't help, this needs higher lower level of javascript probably

Comment: None is actually not a valid value for background-color. Use "transparent" instead.

Comment: "you cannot modify css properties directly within the head tag" — Yes, you can.

Comment: The question isn't about setting the background colour to transparent, it is about removing the invalid section from the rule. i.e. the bold bit here: #00bf00 **00bf00** url

Comment: @Quentin yes, can you suggest a solution?

Comment: Not off the top of my head. I've never needed to investigate what different browsers expose via the DOM Stylesheet interface when given invalid rules.

Answer (score 0):

As Quentin has said, the browser may already have removed this rule, so you can't really edit it.

One the other hand, you can take a look at client side css parsing. LESS has a client side version of their CSS processor, which essentially looks at the available CSS source, and modifies it before returning it to the browser. The LESS source code is open source, so you can see how it does this. Unfortunately, this is a rather complicated process and overkill for something like this. You would be much better off fixing the CSS before it gets delivered to the browser.

Comment: The question isn't about setting the background colour to transparent, it is about removing the invalid section from the rule. i.e. the bold bit here: #00bf00 **00bf00** url

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the style of an element that already exists then just do

```
document.body.style.background = '#00bf00 url(\'images/low.png\') repeat';
```

If you need to change the style itself to make it apply to future elements as well then overwrite the selector with the correct value.

```
$('head').append('<style>#main { background:#00bf00 url(\'images/low.png\') repeat;  }  </style>')
```

(this example assumes the existing style is in the head, so that the new one is inserted after the existing one)